# Get the Key and Value of a dictionary while using random

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a simple "Game"
I'm trying to get the health of the monsters but only the names come up. 
I can do `(random.choice(list(Monster.health.keys())))` and `(random.choice(list(Monster.health.Values())))` to store both the name and health in a variable but I'm using `random` so the name might say 'goblin' but the health may say '50' which is wrong.

How can I store the variable in `random_mon_name_health` and access both 'keys' and 'value'

```
class Monster:
    health = {'goblin': 15, 'giant': 50}


class EncounterM(Monster):
    random_mon_name_health = ''

    def basic_monster(self):
        import random
        self.random_mon_name_health = (random.choice(list(Monster.health.keys()))) 

    def test(self):
        print(self.random_mon_name_health)


beta_user = EncounterM()
beta_user.basic_monster()
beta_user.test()  
# This is only a section of the game that I'm having trouble with
```

Comment: you could use `.items()` which is a "list" or "iterator" of tuples containing the key and the value.

Comment: if you get a random key and a random value then they are unrelated, just get a random key then the associated value will be `Monster.health[k]` where `k` was the key that was chosen.

Comment: This isn't related, but you should really take the time to learn how classes work in Python. They are not exactly like Java classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to call `choice` once, like so:

```
class Monster:
    health = {'goblin': 15, 'giant': 50}

class EncounterM(Monster):
    def __init__(self):
        self.random_mon_name = ''
        self.random_mon_health = 0

    def basic_monster(self):
        import random
        self.random_mon_name, self.random_mon_health = \
            random.choice(list(Monster.health.items()))

    def test(self):
        print(self.random_mon_name, self.random_mon_health)


beta_user = EncounterM()
beta_user.basic_monster()
beta_user.test()
```

Comment: in python 3 `dict.items()` returns a `ItemsView` instead of a `list` so you need to cast it to a list before passing it to `random.choice`,   so it would look like: `random.choice(list(Monster.health.items()))` to be forward compatible.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Good point. I was assuming Python 2, but have no real reason to. I'll edit the answer to include a cast so it'll work in either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store both key an value at `self.random_mon_name_health` you can change your method to something like that and it will return a tuple with the monster name and its associated health.

```
def basic_monster(self):
    import random
    random_key = (random.choice(list(Monster.health.keys())))
    self.random_mon_name_health = random_key, Monster.health[random_key]
```